# returning the stream when there is no gulp.dest in Gulp

Tags: error-handling, gulp, eslint

I have this gulp task

```
gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.scripts.src)
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
    .on('error', notify.onError('<%= error.message %>'));
});
```

Which basically lints my code and outputs the errors in the console while also displaying a notification with `gulp-notify`.

It runs fine when is called through gulp watch on the changed files, but it doesn't work if I call it in a stream of other tasks like this:

```
runSequence(['markup', 'styles', 'lint', 'browserify', 'images', 'fonts'], 'watch', cb);
```

unless of course i put a `.pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))` at the end of the task, but it is redundant bacause it writes the file.

So how should I go about this?

EDIT: [here](https://github.com/marcofugaro/gulp-frontend-boilerplate/blob/master/tasks/stylelint.js) is the example task, and [here](https://github.com/marcofugaro/gulp-frontend-boilerplate/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js#L57) is the runSequence which fails if [this line](https://github.com/marcofugaro/gulp-frontend-boilerplate/blob/master/tasks/stylelint.js#L20) is removed, to execute the project just run `npm install` and then `npm start`

Comment: It breaks if I don't put it and I don't know why.

Comment: [Here is the task](https://github.com/marcofugaro/gulp-frontend-boilerplate/blob/master/tasks/lint.js) and [here](https://github.com/marcofugaro/gulp-frontend-boilerplate/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js#L53) is the runSequence, to execute just run `npm install` and then `npm start`

Comment: What happens when it "breaks"? Does the `lint` task complete, but then kill the `runSequence` task? Or does the `lint` task not complete? Or..?

Comment: No, it doesn't complete and the `runSequence` tasks stops, but you can `CTRL+C` out of it. I updated the links also.

Comment: Sounds like the lint task is failing the `make sure they either return a stream or promise, or handle the callback` (cf. https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence). I've been tripped up by similar trouble recently… will let you know if I learn how best to handle it, and until then will be watching this with interest

Comment: Yes somehow if I return a stream with no `gulp.dest` it is not a valid stream or something...